# Python: string , uuid, datatime

Tags: python, datetime, uuid

I will try to explain my problem I need a string, with this format:

```
Message: ("IdTrace":5f26da31afe24a30ae448222aa76a4ae,Data:2017-02-18T20:17:57. 0000000+01:00",TraceSenderId" :856h3fc-3o7a-48j9-80b5- 23w0f567b931,Value:True, OriginalValue":True")
```

Every time I sent this message i need a new UUID in IdTrace, and I do this:

```
u = str(uuid.uuid4())
uu = u.replace("-", "")
```

Also with the current data:

```
i = str(datetime.datetime.now())
```

But I need the value of the variable uu and i, because message it must be a string, does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: No, because you haven't explained what the problem is. What do you need to do with u, uu and i, and what's stopping you?

Comment: Every time I sent "Message" i need a new UUID in IdTrace and the current data in Data, but i can't use the variables uu and i cause i need a string, if i write: "IdTrace":uu, "Data":i , in Message it is no longer a string

Comment: This question isn't really about `datetime` and `uuid`, it's about how to format strings. Take out everything about `datetime` and `uuid`, and see what question you're left with.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you want to obtain uu and i in the format that has to be inserted in the message. Then the variables are inserted in the message. The message has to be in a string format. To convert the datetime to a string format it is useful to use the strftime, with this you can create a string date format that is needed. See the following link for more information: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

The example code to get the message that is wanted with the variable uu and i can be the following:

```
import uuid
import datetime
u = str(uuid.uuid4())
uu = u.replace("-", "") 
print uu
i=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%dT-%H-%M-%S")
print i
msg= 'Message:("IdTrace:"'+uu+',Data:'+i+')'
print msg
```

The message printed out in the end is in string format. The code will print the following:

```
98b760288f3c4182a423ba7ba7cf2b2c
17-03-02T-12-13-25
Message:("IdTrace:"98b760288f3c4182a423ba7ba7cf2b2c,Data:17-03-02T-12-13-25)
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterWood for the useful information. Edited the post.

Comment: @PaulVelthuis Thanks is exactly that my problem, now i am trying! :)